# How can I drop aggro against monsters while playing solo?

Tags: diablo-iii

On numerous occasions, I've needed to run away from enemies and retreat to safety by dropping aggro so that the enemy will give up their pursuit. Sometimes, it seems quite easy. Other times, however, the monster seems content to chase me for quite a while before ultimately giving up. I'm curious if there are any general-purpose rules of thumb out there regarding how and when aggro can be dropped in a single-player game (with or without a Follower).

Is it merely based on distance between you and the enemy, line-of-sight, pursuit time, or something else? Does it vary between normal and Champion/Rare/Unique monsters? Are there any other factors that go into it?

While I'm aware that certain class-specific abilities exist for doing this (Smoke Screen, etc.), I'm specifically interested in the general mechanics of how to drop aggro when attempting to run away, regardless of class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does aggro work in Diablo III?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67003/how-does-aggro-work-in-diablo-iii)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the answers on the question [How does aggro work in Diablo III?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67003/how-does-aggro-work-in-diablo-iii), aggro is triggered by damage and proximity. **And** each period of time a monster will lose aggro and search for a new target.

According to this, if you want to drop aggro from monsters you need to run away and slow them down to gain distance from them. Then, once their time to reassign aggro comes, the'll will look for a new target. But since you are far enough from them (hopefully), and didn't hurt them, they'll leave you alone.

So, in order to gain this:

- Don't use any DOT (damage over time), as it'll refocus their aggro on you due to the damage done.
- If you have any +speed gear, put it on
- Use slowing of freezing abilities (**that don't cause DOT**)
- Relocation abilities such as [teleport](http://diablo3area.com/diablo3-wizard-skills.php#Teleport) or [leap attack](http://diablo3area.com/diablo3-barbarian-skills.php#leap-attack) will help you, especially if they can make you jump over a gap that the monsters can't cross.
- Abilities with knock back might help to get a head start.
- **DO NOT ATTACK ENEMIES WITH NON SLOWING POWERS DURING THE ESCAPE!!!**

Comment: If you are playing Monk, don't forget you can use Dash on 'piles' of things to quickly get out of a fight.

Comment: After doing some more testing of my own, yeah, simply putting as much distance as possible between the monster and yourself seems to be the most reliable way. The notion of monsters periodically re-checking for targets every few seconds based on damage and proximity also seems to line up pretty well with what I've seen in practice.

Answer (score 2):

The monsters will stop chasing you when they lost their aggro towards you.

You can get extra information about Aggro in Diablo-3 in ["**How does aggro work in Diablo III?**"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67003/how-does-aggro-work-in-diablo-iii)

Once 3 Champions/Rare mobs (blue and yellow) followed me for 4 maps until the city. That was scary.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Unfortunately, the linked question doesn't seem to go much into the specifics as to how that all works, such as how aggro-dropping would work in a single-player situation. (Does it decay automatically over time?)

Comment: the aggro drop in a single player, makes the enemies go to your follower, or stay in the same place as they were before. The aggro is by range, so the drop is total, not over time.

Comment: OK, "by range" is more along the lines of what I'm looking for; I'm interested to see some more information/data on that. I know that an enemy stops following you when they drop aggro, but what I want to know is precisely *how* you drop aggro when playing solo. I've edited the question for more clarity.

Comment: @cloudymusic You want to know more about aggro. in this case, I would suggest you to keep an eye in the post that I linked.

Comment: Yeah, there's some decent stuff in there, but that discussion seems almost entirely centered around group play (how you can pull aggro off another player, etc). Hopefully some more information on this surfaces.