# How far is too far?

Tags: diablo-iii

I met this foe and I didn't get too close, then I throw a hydra at it, and realized it wasn't coming towards me, so I went on archon form and started punishing him with my pew pew laser beam, he still never came to me, and so he died.

[image: Screenshot of situation]
[*Enlarge*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeVcf.jpg)

What is the range of "awareness" of monsters, and what is the maximum range of ranged spells like placing a hydra somewhere, or the archon's beam power?

By the way the templar was hitting him while Leah just stood by my side.

Comment: By the way... how did you manage to have 2 Zoltun Kulle following you? :D

Comment: He likes me that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't the range of "awareness" as you put it.  This is a currently known issue (will find the report shortly), the same thing happens to monsters that are chasing you and all the sudden "freeze" or stop pursuit, but allow you to wail on them.  This link on [aggro](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67003/how-does-aggro-work-in-diablo-iii) may also serve some value to you as to what causes monsters to do what they do.