# Why do enemies prefer to go after me instead of my Templar?

Tags: diablo-iii

I am running around yet my Templar is ignored and I, the wizard, is being chased.

How do I make this meat damage soaker useful?

Comment: You deal much much more damage than he does, thus you are the greater threat. Just do not attack the opponent he is fighting against atm. He is no real tank.

Comment: I think it goes beyond that.  Even before fights start, I notice some melee units rushing at me (the DH) and totally ignoring the Monk who is a screen distance ahead of me.  I think there's a system in place that prevents anybody from pulling all the aggro unless there's literally no one nearby.

Comment: Related to: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67003/how-does-aggro-work-in-diablo-iii

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is no real "agro" in diablo. Its more so on the highest dps. So your templar is not really gonna tank much. You can set him up to jump on you and knock things away.

Comment: There is a simple threat system based on proximity and damage (Templar even has a taunt ability). You will obviously severely out damage your Templar though.

Comment: Ah ya, I gave my templar good gear now.